# Restarting program and checking for previously accomplished progress

Tags: design-patterns

I am writing a deep-learning program in Python.

I'd like my program do the following steps (the exact steps are irrelevant, the pattern is important):

1. Download the images and store them on disk.
2. Train the neural net
3. make predictions using the trained neural net.

Downloading and training takes quite a while, and when shutting down my computer I'd like to continue where I left off. I'd like to not having to download all images again after changing some neural network details too. This gave rise to the following consideration: **Why not store the progress of the application?** So, I am thinking of somehow implementing the following design:

```
for step in steps:
  check if already accomplished this step (make sure, if input-state to following steps is correct).
  if check = True:
    skip this step
  else:
    do this step and all of the following steps without checking.
```

I added the `do this step and all of the following steps without checking` since it is not known whether not accomplishing this step changes the result of the following steps.

for example in my case this would be like:

```
check if images are downloaded - 
if downloaded
  check if neural network already trained
  if trained
    predict
  else
    train the net
    predict

else:
  download images
  do following steps in order without checking whether already accomplished
```

I got the following questions:

1. Does this pattern have a name? I googled memoization and caching but both of them don't really fit, since it is about the side effects (e.g. downloading and storing the images) as well.
2. Is there any standard way to  implement such a pattern? I personally thought of writing a class for each step with a `do_step` and `check_if_already_done` method.
3. Do you have good ideas how to implement such a pattern?

Comment: Probably not significant enough to be considered a "pattern", but persistent state is the most accurate term I use.

Comment: Use state machines and serialization.